# How to see dependencies between artifacts in Artifactory?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, artifactory

I have installed Artifactory 3.2.0 (free version) on my computer and it is relatively easy to use but I am confused when it comes to viewing the dependencies between artifacts.

As a trial run, I uploaded an artifact with default pom, but added in

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>text</groupId>
   <artifactId>trial2</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <type>txt</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

which is the dependency declaration of another file.  However I do not see anything indicating the two dependencies between the two artifacts.  Is this what artifactory is like?  Or is there something wrong with my installation of artifactory?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, binary repository does not include dependency manager of its own, so it does not know about the dependencies between artifacts. This is due to the fact that there is a whole plead of  dependency managers, each of them resolves dependencies a bit differently (specially, when it comes to transitive dependencies). Even one tool can switch the resolution strategy between versions. 
That means that doing *static* dependency analysis correctly is almost impossible, so when you just upload the files, Artifactory doesn't know about the dependencies.

This changes, when Artifactory has a chance to do a *runtime* dependency analysis. If you run a build (effectively resolving the artifacts using the dependency manager of choice) and Artifactory is aware of it (by using one of the [Build Integration plugins](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration), [Maven plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) or [Gradle plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Gradle)), then boom! you can see all the dependencies in the build browser:
[image]